# Captivate 8 Assessment with 3 Attempts and Random Questions From Multiple Pools

Tags: javascript, scorm, adobe-captivate

**Problem**:
Need an assessment to randomly pull a subset of questions from multiple pools for a maximum of three attempts.

- Prescribed number of questions are presented in a random pull from the question pools for the first attempt.
- Second and Third attempts at quiz are presented with the same questions in the same order as the first quiz was, thus defeating the purpose of having questions randomly selected from pools
- Cp Retake button merely launches the same quiz with the same questions in the same order.

---

I've tried forcing the user to exit (no retake button and individual slides for each outcome including 3 failure slides) and relaunch from the LMS with a flag var to let it know to go to the retake slide upon re-entry, but it still presents the same q's in the same order.

In order to get a fresh set of questions it appears that the page needs to be reloaded (which I thought was happening in the above exit/relaunch scenario).

I've created a homemade "retake" button that calls JavaScript:

```
window.top.location.reload(true);
```

Two problems with this approach:

1. You have to forgo the resume (cmi.location), so learners have to
   start all over instead of returning to where they left off. Not
   good, as we have dozens of questions and the learner shouldn't be
   forced to one session.
2. You lose track of the number of attempts as the variables are
   re-initialized upon reload. I tried assigning the cpQuizInfoAttempts
   system var to a numAttempts user var hoping it would persist, but
   both are reset upon reload.

Since we need the number of failures as a persistent var stored on the LMS server, I tried contacting Rustici support (since their scormdriver.js is used in Cp8) to see if I could use three objectives and use cmi.objectives.n.score.max (or cmi.suspend_data), and using JavaScript to get/set values like:

```
SCORM_CallLMSSetValue('cmi.suspend_data','');
```

but haven't gotten to solution yet.

The next workaround tack is to try and use a multi-sco course with three instances of the same assessment, each with one attempt, and have the course success show completed upon the pass of one, and failed upon failing all three assessments. The issue here is that, using one of the three out of the box templates such as Multiple SCOs, the scores are averaged. I'm going to go in the template code and hack it to try and get the max score instead of average.

Any other angles to solving this?

Comment: You asked for other angles: have you tried publishing as for Tin Can tracking? You might run into exactly the same problems, but possibly the bookmarking is done differently - it's another angle to try.

Comment: Thanks, Andrew. Going to try and keep it SCORM 2004 4th edition assome of the targeted LMS do not yet support Tin Can.